# RMarkdown document - How to delay knitr evaluation of an inline code piece until later chunks have processed?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I've created an rmarkdown report, with a bunch of code chunks. I'm now creating a summary front page for it, and would like to include an inline calculation like

```
Blah blah blah summary stuff.... We found the mean to be `r mean(some_object_from_the_report)`. Blah blah blah more summary stuff.
```

Being at the start of the RMD file, some_object_from_the_report doesn't exist yet. Is there any way to tell knitr to hold off evaluating that code snippet until after the later items have all been computed?

Thanks for any tips!

EDIT:

Suggestion as comment is to set echo=false in knitr options. Either I'm doing it wrong, or it doesn't help my situation. The following short example illustrates this.

````
---
title: "Minimal test of delayed evaluation"
author: "sff"
date: "December 13, 2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Summary

Summary of blahblahblah. Also here's a mean from the report: `r mean(testobj)`.


## Report

```{r report_stuff}
testobj <- c(1, 2, 3)
```
````

Knitr throws an object not found error. Am I implementing the suggestion wrongly, or does the suggestion not achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display chunk output before echoing code in Rmarkdown presentation (slidy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869378/how-to-display-chunk-output-before-echoing-code-in-rmarkdown-presentation-slidy)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mako. Example below throws error. Little help?

    ---  
    title: "Minimal test of delayed evaluation"  
    author: "sff"  
    date: "December 13, 2017"  
    output: html_document  
    ---  
  
    ```{r setup, include=TRUE}  
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)  
    ```  
  
    ## Summary  
  
    Summary of blahblahblah. Also here's a mean from the report: `r mean(testobj)`.
  
    ## Report  
  
    ```{r report_stuff}  
    testobj <- c(1, 2, 3)  
    ```
What am I missing?

Comment: What I usually do is create an empty list with fields to be calculated, they are later filled in during the script and saved as Rdata. First thing next time I load this list. This requires running the script two times, but I use this for summaries at the beginning of articles.

Comment: @Cedric So the idea is the first time it runs nothing is populated in the output, but the calculations are saved, so the 2nd time it runs the calcs are loaded and then show in the output?

Comment: Yes I'll give an example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working example, you set a first chunk before the abstract, it can be set at the very beginning of the document if you need to adjust other thigs like `\graphicspath{}`.

In this chunk you create a list if the Rdata file containing the list does not exist. You need to populate it with the values called in the text.

When first running the example you get
[image: first run]

On the second run you get

[image: second run]

Note that this way, you can avoid running long calculation and simply save their results.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\title{Testing how to save results for the abstract}
\author{}
\begin{document}
% this chunk comes just after begin{document}
<< init, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE,results="hide" >>=
require(knitr)
summary_list_path <-paste0(getwd(),"/data/summary_list.Rdata")
if (!file.exists(summary_list_path)){
  summary_list<-list()
  summary_list[["A"]]<-list()
  summary_list[["B"]]<-list()
  summary_list[["A"]][["N"]]<-NA
  summary_list[["A"]][["p"]]<-NA
  summary_list[["B"]][["text"]]<-"extremely sad"
} else {
  load(summary_list_path)
}
@
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
My population is \Sexpr{summary_list[["A"]][["N"]]} and the p value was \Sexpr{summary_list[["A"]][["p"]]} as a result I am \Sexpr{summary_list[["B"]][["text"]]}
\end{abstract}

<<chunk_1, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE,results="hide" >>=
summary_list[["A"]][["N"]]<-20
summary_list[["A"]][["p"]]<-0.05
# save your list at the end of each chunk, that was you can also avoid 
# processing everyting.
save(summary_list,file=summary_list_path)
@

<<chunk_2, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE,results="hide" >>=
summary_list[["B"]][["text"]]<-"happy"
save(summary_list,file=summary_list_path)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Got it. Serialization as an alternative to delayed evaluation. Thanks for the concrete example!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

1. Create a chunk (or several) before your abstract.
2. Use the chunk(s) to import and clean data.
3. Then calculate each one of the values that appears in the abstract, saving each one to a named object.
4. Now just reference the named objects in your inline code in the abstract (rather than doing the calculations themselves).

Advantages:

- All the calculations are already done and saved so you can also refer to them later in your report.
- Because all the data pre-processing is already done in the chunks before your abstract, later chunks of r code in the report can just focus on creating figures, tables or performing more complex analyses.
- The objects (results of the calculations) won't appear until you explicitly call them (the pre-abstract chunks won't have any visible output until the abstract itself).

Here's an example:

````r
```{r setup, include=FALSE}

# Set chunk options:
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE, 
                      warning = FALSE, 
                      eval = TRUE)
```

```{r packages}

# Check if pacman is installed, install if not:
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")

# Use pacman to load the rest of the required packages (below are examples):
pacman::p_load(
  rmarkdown,
  knitr, 
  tidyverse,
  officedown,
  officer, 
  rio,
  here
)

```

```{r import_data}

mydata <- rio::import(here("data", "mydata.xlsx")) %>%

   # Data cleaning steps...

```

```{r abstract_figs}

# Calculate figures for the abstract:

n_cases <- nrow(mydata)

```

# Abstract

This is an abstract. There were `r n_cases` recruited to the study.
````